# Graphic output for Ripleys K function

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, spatial-statistics, statistics

I am using ArcGIS to calculate Ripleys K function using the "Multi-Distance Spatial Cluster Analysis (Ripleys K Function)" tool on a point feature class. I can see a table output but want a graphical output too.

There is an option to Display Results Graphically but that does nothing. In the messages it does say something about Result Image: KFuncation but believe me there is no image output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your table in ArcMAP, click the button in the upper left corner of the table and select "create graph", plot k against distance as a point or line graph. This could also be done in a spreadsheet program.

Comment: worked. thank you. What is the Graphically option for then if I have to do it by myself?! St**id software.